# Using VBA to insert a formula gives me error

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

As i failed to convert my excel formula to a vba compatible one, i decided to simply insert the value as follows:

`Range("AB3").Formula = "=MID($AA3;FIND(CHAR(134);SUBSTITUTE($AA3;AB$2;CHAR(134);1))+22;FIND(CHAR(134);SUBSTITUTE($AA3;AC$2;CHAR(134);1))-FIND(CHAR(134);SUBSTITUTE($AA3;AB$2;CHAR(134);1))-25)"`

Unfortunately it gives me a run-time error 1004, which is weird since if i try remove the first "=" and then adding it manually, the formula works in excel...

Would any of you know what the issue is ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Replace the semicolons with commas.

Comment: It's as simple as that wow, thanks

Comment: Yes, and asked 1000 times

Comment: ...or you can use `.FormulaLocal` and keep the `;`